# Is something happening with Ethereum Sepolia (or Etherscan Sepolia)?

Tags: etherscan, sepolia

I have came across several strange behaviours in the past couple of days with Ethereum Sepolia:

- While using Web3J in an application of mine, transactions are only processed in batches after a couple of hours;
- A transaction from Chainlink's faucet, simply vanished from [Etherscan](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xf4a27a53b4d7fa7da82aa3c6c48f700131f22ce9310175c219d02471533c85fd) (I know this hash is correct, as it once appeared to be processing, but after some minutes it was no longer able to locate it);
- I deployed and verified the same contract 4 days ago and yesterday to test wether custom errors would show on Etherscan or not. On the contract from 4 days ago [I see the custom errors](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x813a22c859fcb7e7436f102faaefeaf554c5b43b04f09ed8621570913556ae46) while on the contract deployed yesterday, [it does not](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xf0613906ec6aedc05424b8cae0dc2e90515d135aa5af8ff9137b5f523e42a5b4).

Regarding the first issue, I suspect that it may have been due to Web3J automatically setting low gas such that it only gets mined after a while. However, the other two issues are something I've never faced.

I saw online that there were some recent issues with Etherscan Sepolia when it comes to verifying contracts, but nothing that would affect what I am seeing.

Would anyone know the reason for this recent strange behaviour?

Comment: Sepoliascan/Etherscan is a closed source third party explorer. Unfortunately they don't provide help here. If you have some issues it is better to contact their customer support.